# how to add multiline item and subitem in listview in VB6?

Tags: listview, vb6, addition, subitem

i have data in textbox like this:

[image: object]

i want to split 3 type of that data to 3 coloums in listview. i know how to split that data by character using this type of code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String

Dim i As Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
sLines() = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(sLines)
   If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
      sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")
      a = sValues(0) & vbCrLf
      b = sValues(1) & vbCrLf
      c = sValues(2) & vbCrLf
      Set List = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , a)
      ListView1.ListItems.Add.SubItems(1) = b
      ListView1.ListItems.Add.SubItems(2) = c
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

but the result is like this:

[image: result]

it isn't linier with the line. 
what happen with my code? is it wrong?
please help me, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try something like this, you could actually loop through the values array using a for i .. loop, but you get the gist!

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String

Dim i As Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
Dim oItem As ListItem

sLines() = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(sLines)
   If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
      sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")
      a = sValues(0) & vbCrLf
      b = sValues(1) & vbCrLf
      c = sValues(2) & vbCrLf

      Set oItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , sValues(0))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(1))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(2))
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: diastri, remove all lines with a, b and c  variables, are unnecessary to populate ListView.

Comment: Good point @GiorgioBrausi, they aren't necessary. As I mentioned earlier, I'd also loop through sValues to populate SubItems.